# Bit manipulation, ascii with binary

Tags: c, pic

How does one apply bit manipulation (AND clear, OR set and perhaps XOR to examine) to each bit in a binary? What I would like to do is input a character or string and output the message in binary to a specific output pin on my MCU. I want to use bit manipulation because creating a function for each character on the ascii table would take lots of memory on my MCU.

How is see so far is that I have set the pin output and declared each bit as a variable. Does this make sense so far?

```
void bits (void)
{
    #define RSTEST PORTBbits.RB5 //Declaring the port for serial
    #define RSOUT   TRISBbits.RB5 = 0 //Sets the port RB5 as an output

    unsigned int b0 = 0 ; // Binary 00000000
    unsigned int b1 = 0 ;
    unsigned int b2 = 0 ;
    unsigned int b3 = 0 ;
    unsigned int b4 = 0 ;
    unsigned int b5 = 0 ;
    unsigned int b6 = 0 ;
    unsigned int b7 = 0 ;

}
```

The reason I am trying to do this is because writing a function for each ASCII code is long and uncessary memory space.

```
void main(void)
{

      while (1)
    {
             RSTEST ; // same config as above
//           RSOUT = 1 ; // MSB
//           __delay_ms(10); 
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // START
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 1
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 1 ; // 2
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 3
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 1 ; // 4
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 5
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 6
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 1 ; // 7
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 8
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 1 ; // STOP
//           
//           RSOUT = 1 ; // MSB
//           __delay_ms(10); 
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // START
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 1
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 2
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 3
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 4
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 1 ; // 5
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 1 ; // 6
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 7
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 8
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 1 ; // STOP
//           
//           RSOUT = 1 ; // MSB
//           __delay_ms(10); 
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // START
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 1 ; // 1
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 2
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 1 ; // 3
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 4
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 5
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 6
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 1 ; // 7
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 0 ; // 8
//           __delay_us(25);
//           RSOUT = 1 ; // STOP

    }
}
```

All those lines just to print JOE.

Can I just something similar to printf("JOE");

I do not want to use Tx and Rx Hardware EUSART but Software EUSART.

Comment: Use `>>=` shift to iterate over bits. `while (val) { output(val & 1); val >>= 1; }`

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: Why don't use the hardware UART? A lott of PIC will support it.

Comment: Because I want to experiment with software UART.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a function like this, using MSB first:

```
#define MSB 1
#define LSB 0

void out_char(char character, char bit_order){

  uint8_t i = 0;
  RSOUT = 1 ; // MSB
  __delay_ms(10); 
  RSOUT = 0 ; // START
  __delay_us(25);
  for (i = 8; i>0; --i){
      if (bit_order){
        RSOUT = (character & 0x80) ? 1:0;
        character <<= 1;
      } else {
        RSOUT = (character & 0x01);
        character >>= 1;
      }
      __delay_us(25);
  }
  RSOUT = 1 ; // STOP

}

void out_str(char * string, uint8_t len, char bit_order){
  uint8_t i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i< len; i++){
    out_char(string[i], bit_order);
  }
}

out_str("Hello world",11, MSB); // 'H' 0x48 will be '0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0'    
out_str("Hello world",11, LSB); // 'H' 0x48 will be '0-0-0-1-0-0-1-0'
```

Comment: I will give this a try. Is that just for character? How it be for a string like a sentence?

Comment: you can iterate, knowing the length of the string. I edited the answer.

Comment: Hi Gustav, I cannot see any difference so far. How would you do it say for example, print a sentence "Hello World"?

Comment: Yes I have it now. I will try and let you know in a few mins.

Comment: I get an error about the uint8_t. Cannot this be int?

Comment: Add `#include <stdint.h>` for uint8_t, it's a [standard type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) and as far as i remember available on pic. Use `unsigned char` in case of no `uint8_t`, but in case of string length maybe `unsigned int` or `size_t` would be better type.

Comment: Fantastic! I don't get the error now. I did what you said and it works. Only one little problem, I get scrambled characters in serial terminal. I have the frequency set to 16MHz I set the baud rate at 38400. Is this the right speed?

Comment: You should be aware if you are using MSB or LSB when taking out the bits. The example I provided is using MSB approach, I modified to select the bit order.

Comment: What do you mean? Does that affect the baud rate?

Comment: Not the baud rate at all. Suppose you have the character `'G' = 0x47 = 0b01000111`, you must decide how will you send it through one pin, **Most Significative Bit** first or **Less Significative Bit** first. With MSB will be '0-1-0-0-0-1-1-1' and LSB will be '1-1-1-0-0-0-1-0'.

Comment: So if I want to send hello world it would be out_str("Hello world",11, MSB);? I don't know why I get scrambled text in serial.

Comment: Did you tried using 'LSB'? Also, could you provide those "scrambled bytes". Try sending `"F6B"`, if you receive `"blj"`, bit order is your problem.

Comment: Yes I got scrambled. Sure I will send it to you one moment. I will also send F6B

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183735/discussion-between-m2t156-and-gustavovelascoh).

Comment: I think from what I have tested it's a timing problem. The code is very logical and appears to work fine as I am seeing MSD, START, 8 bits and STOP.